# Program cannot identify when username is correct sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I cannot get this login program to take the username and password fetched from database and compare it to entered one. It just says that the username is incorrect when it is not. Please help thanks

```
def loginpage():
    bottom= Toplevel()
    bottom.title("SmartCards - Login")
    bottom.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\Comp NEA\Icon.ico")
    bottom.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    
    def submit2():
        user1 = username1.get()
        passwrd1 = password1.get()
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE "user1" == username'
        sql2 = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'passwrd1' == password"
        c.execute(sql)
        c.execute(sql2)
        conn.commit()
        if sql==user1:
            if sql2==passwrd1:
                messagebox.showinfo("Success","Login Successful!")
                
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Error","Password Incorrect!")
        
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error","Username Incorrect!")
    
    userbox = Label (bottom, text="Username:")
    userbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
    username1 = Entry(bottom)
    username1.insert(0,"")
    username1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    passbox1 = Label (bottom, text="Password:")
    passbox1.grid(row=2, column=0)
    password1 = Entry(bottom)
    password1.insert(0,"")
    password1.grid(row=3, column=0)
    submit = Button(bottom, text="Submit", command=submit2)
    submit.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

Comment: `if sql2==passwrd1` You're comparing the SQL query string itself, and of course that is not equal to the password.  You need to fetch the RESULT of the query.

Comment: And your queries are wrong anyway, because they use the literal strings `"user1"` and `"password1"`, instead of using the values of those **variables**.

Comment: is it possible you could help me solve these problems in code

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: As a side note: you never store passwords in clear text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single query for both username and password, with placeholder tokens instead of literal values:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = %s AND password = %s'
```

Then execute the query, providing actual values for the placeholders:

```
c.execute(sql, [user1, password1])
```

Then fetch the results of the query and look at how many matching rows were found:

```
results = c.fetchall()
if len(results) == 0:
    # no matching users were found.  failure.
elif len(results) == 1:
    # exactly one matching user was found.  success!
else:
    # more than one user was found.  this is probably a failure?
```